# Proove role Normal permission in Android Pie

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am supposed to write a code that causes an Exception/Problem(something not working) when some normal permission are not written in the manifest. However, I have some problem to reach any exception/problems for these Permission:

> BROADCAST_STICKY
>
> GET_PACKAGE_SIZE
>
> INSTALL_SHORTCUT
>
> REQUEST_COMPANION_RUN_IN_BACKGROUND
>
> NFC

Do you know how to do it for at least some of them?

Comment: What are you asking, exactly? How to cause an Exception? If you `sendStickyBroadcast()` without the `BROADCAST_STICKY`, it'll throw a `SecurityException`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes exactly. But which intent are you using?

Comment: Any, really. You could probably just do it with a blank `Intent` – i.e., `sendStickyBroadcast(new Intent());` – since it likely does the permission check first thing.

Comment: And is it also working for Pie? Because i think stickybroadcast are deprecated in Pie

Comment: So it would be even more likely to cause a problem, then, yeah? Is that the goal? Or did I misunderstand what you're asking how to do?

Comment: No sorry...what i mean is i want an application that work with the permission (or at least does not cause any error/exception) and one that does not work (or at least cause an error that i can see in the log) wothout the permission

Comment: Sorry, I really don't understand what you're asking, then.

Comment: Basically i want an application that does not have one of these permission on its manifest and reach an error/exception causes by the absence of this permission on the manifest (and not cause by sth else)

Comment: Well, sticky broadcasts are deprecated mainly for security reasons. That doesn't necessarily mean they don't work anymore, if set up properly.

Comment: Yes! it is working! Thx...I still have these perimssions to do : GET_PACKAGE_SIZE
INSTALL_SHORTCUT
REQUEST_COMPANION_RUN_IN_BACKGROUND

But thank you!